# Calculator for Addition 3 private double data members with three public properties

Tags: c#

Calculator Version 1

Create a Console project.

Rename "Program.cs" to "CalculatorRun.cs"

Add class "Calculator.cs"
- 3 private double data members with three public properties
- firstOperand, FirstOperand;
- secondOperand, SecondOperand;
- result, Result;

- 1 public method Addition()
- do addition in this method, Result = FirstOperand + SecondOperand;

In "CalculatorRun.cs", have users to enter values for firstOperand and secondOperand,
show addtion result.

I have worked on this for hours and it makes no sense still. My code is useless. Does anyone have input?

This is what I have:

```
namespace CalculatorRun
{
    class Calculator
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal FirstOperand, SecondOperand, Result, result;
            Console.Write("Addition Calculation");
            Console.Write("      \n\n");
            Console.Write("   Enter first operand:       ");
            FirstOperand = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("   Enter second operand:      ");
            SecondOperand = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("-------------------------\n\n");
            Result = FirstOperand + SecondOperand;
            result = Convert.ToDecimal(Result);
            Console.WriteLine("Addition Result: {0}", string.Format("{0}", result));
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.....");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But it needs to be more like this (of course using the directions at the top). But when I have tried it, I can't get it to work. : 
    using System;

```
namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }//<-----------

        public int number01;
        public int number02;
        public int Number03
        {
            get
            {
                return number02 / number01;
            }
        }//<----------

        class Program1 : Program
        {

            public void DivideFinal()//<---- void not int
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a number to be divided: ");
                Console.ReadKey();
                number01 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter another number to be divided");
                number02 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
                Console.WriteLine("The result is: " + Number03);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How can we provide an input if you didn't post your code? Here in SO you must be specific when asking questions so that it won't get closed.

Comment: I apologize. I updated it.

Comment: your code is confusing. Program1 inherits from Program. why?

Comment: addition code seems to be working. what is not working here?

Comment: My biggest issue is I don't understand how to add the requirements he wants, as wanting a public and private and a get and return because it seems to not be needed when just using only addition. So what I am missing is (for example only)   public int number01;
        public int number02;
        public int Number03
        {
            get
            {
                return number02 / number01;
            }

Comment: In order to do this you need to understand what is a field and what is a property. assignement states you need 3 private fields and 3 public properties that returns those fields. but you don't have any private fields,you only have to public fields and a  public property.

Comment: Although I would say the wording of the assignment is poor, instead of members it could say fields.

Comment: Yes, there has been an issue with the wording of the assignment and entire lectures being very poor. It is very confusing when I go back to try and get information and study to distinguish what he really wanted. So now I am confused because since all I have is firstOperand, FirstOperand; - secondOperand, SecondOperand; - result, Result; does that need a private and public property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it for you. Explanation in comments:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {

        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

            Console.Write( "   Enter first operand:       " );

            calculator.FirstOperand = Convert.ToDouble( Console.ReadLine() ); //get the first

            Console.Write( "   Enter first operand:       " );

            calculator.SecondOperand = Convert.ToDouble( Console.ReadLine() ); //get the second

            calculator.Addition(); //Do addition

            Console.WriteLine( "Addition Result: {0}", calculator.Result ); //show result

            Console.WriteLine( "Press any key to continue....." );
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    class Calculator {
        private double firstOperand, secondOperand, result; //double data members

        //3 public properties
        public double FirstOperand {
            get { return firstOperand; }
            set { firstOperand = value; }
        }

        public double SecondOperand {
            get { return secondOperand; }
            set { secondOperand = value; }
        }

        public double Result {
            get { return result; }
            set { result = value; }
        }

        //1 public method Addition()
        public double Addition() {
            return result = firstOperand + secondOperand;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1513 } expected ConsoleApp2 C:\Users\SamsungTouch\Desktop\School\C#\Assignments\CalculatorRun3\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs 57 Active

Comment: @irrevocably You probably missed a  curly bracket `}`. The above code is inside a name space

Comment: Thank you so much! I believe that is correct. I edited it a little bit so the first "program" is "calculator run"

Comment: @irrevocably don't forget to mark this answer as correct if it is.

Comment: you can get rid of fields like firstOperand, secondOperand and just use public double FirstOperand {
            get;      set;
        }

Comment: @Gauravsa It is the requirements of his assignment. Read his question

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado Thank you for walking me through my first question! I learned a lot about how Stack Overflow works and you were really nice about it. I will make sure to do better next time. γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε Thank you so much for your answer, I had been working on this for over 10 hours and was in tears! It looks so simple, but for someone who is new the wording of the assignment had me so confused I was so worried I was doing it wrong. Thank you for the clarification! Also, thank you to everyone for your input you all helped tremendously! What a wonderful community.